# tinymce removes the textarea

Tags: tinymce, textarea

I have a very weird problem,

first: this is my tiny init:

```
function recargar_tiny(){
                  // General options
      tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Skin options
        skin : "o2k7",
        skin_variant : "silver",

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/style.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
                username : "Some User",
                staffid : "991234"
        }
});

                }
```

And what i do is to load the form via ajax, and then, call the tinymce init

This is the result:
[image: textarea is gone]
Firebug doesn't jumb any error... :?

Please note that there should be a textarea there and there is not... :?

PS: but if i don't do this via ajax, if i do it onload it works fine... this is driving me mad, can you see something?

EDIT2

This is my ajax call with the tiny init

```
function editar_item(id, tipo){
                    // where id and tipo are int ID's
                      $("#router").load('/includes/router.php?que=editar_item&id='+id+'&tipo='+tipo,{},function(){
                            // where <textarea id="texto" name = "texto">
                            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'texto');
                      });

}
```

Now it's not removing the textarea but it isn't loading the wyswyg either.. :?

Any idea?

-EDIT3-

if i do it like this after the jquery ajax call:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "inlinepopups",
    media_strict: false,
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,forecolor,image,link,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,|,removeformat,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent",
    heme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "center",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    editor_deselector : "no_tiny",


    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "/js/tinymce/examples/css/content.css",

    // Style formats
    style_formats : [

            {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Blue text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#006'}},
            {title : 'Blue header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#006'}},
            {title : 'Codigo fuente', inline : 'code', classes : 'prettyprint', exact: true}


    ],

    formats : {
            alignleft : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'left'},
            aligncenter : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'center'},
            alignright : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'right'},
            alignfull : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'full'},
            bold : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'bold'},
            italic : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'italic'},
            underline : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'underline', exact : true},
            strikethrough : {inline : 'del'},
            customformat : {inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#00ff00', fontSize : '20px'}, attributes : {title : 'My custom format'}}
    }
```

});

Then it works!!! but not al the features i need are enabled.... :(

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use mode "exact" in your init

```
mode: 'exact',
```

then when the ajaxrequest is finished you call

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, editorid); //use the textarea id as editor_id here
```

Comment: and this sentece will init the tinymce for the new loaded form? thanks!!

Comment: yes, but you need to be aware that you should shut down an editor instance correctly using mceRemoveControl when the dom element containing the tinymce editor vanishes or gets deleted

Comment: would it be tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, texto); or tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'texto'); if <textarea id="texto"> ??   (nither are working..)

Comment: if 'texto' is your id then it is this one, if texto is a js-variable holding your id as a string it is that one. further information can be found in the documentation:  http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Command_identifiers ; usually the editorid equals the textareas id

Comment: well, as I said <textarea id="texto"> and none of those is helping.. any other idea?

Comment: tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'texto'); should do it with mode 'exact'

Comment: it's not enabling it... :( I had mode: 'textareas', and changed it for mode: 'exact' AND it doesn't enable wyswyg (on body load stills working, dough). I edited my question

Comment: csan you inspect the dom after the ajax call and find out if $("#router") exists. Additionally, you can put an alert before and after the tinymce-init call to see if the function gets called and if it stops while executing.

Comment: yes it exists because i can see the form and it's the <div> wehre i do all the ajax calls.. i edited3 my question with a partial solution as a callback for the jquery ajax call, does it help?

Comment: the problem is that if i insert an <iframe> it get stripped :(

Comment: why do you want to insert an iframe? (this is possible, but needs to be configured properly)

Comment: indeed, but this should not be covered here - i suggest you open a new one for that problem

Comment: ok, and if this answer satisfied you and solved your problem ('tinymce removes the textarea') you should accept the answer (and maybe upvote)

Comment: it actually doesn't as i told you in my coments your sentence doesn't re-activate my wysywg... :(

Comment: can you put your example online, so i could do some tests with it?